# Deezer API and file_put_contents

Tags: php, json, api, deezer

I've got this script for saving albumart from Deezer to my server. The albumart url is alright, you can try yourself. And it does make a file but it's not the image I would like to see but a corrupted file. I am guessing it has something to do with the (I guess) 301 they provide when you visit the original link you get from the API. But I don't know hot to solve that problem if it is that.

```
<?php
// Deezer
$query = 'https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=madonna';
$file = file_get_contents($query);
$parsedFile = json_decode($file);
$albumart = $parsedFile->data[0]->artist->picture;
$artist =  $parsedFile->data[0]->artist->name;

$dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/albumarts/'.$artist.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($dir, $albumart);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) `$albumart` contains a URL (in your case http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/290/image). You need to do `file_get_contents` on that url.

```
<?php 
// Deezer 
$query = 'https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=madonna'; 
$file = file_get_contents($query); 
$parsedFile = json_decode($file); 
$albumart = $parsedFile->data[0]->artist->picture; 
$artist =  $parsedFile->data[0]->artist->name; 

$dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/albumarts/'.$artist.'.jpg'; 
file_put_contents($dir, file_get_contents($albumart));    // << Changed this line
?>
```

2) The redirect may be a problem (as you suggest). To get around that, use curl functions.

```
// Get file using curl.
// NOTE: you can add other options, read the manual
$ch = curl_init($albumart);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Save output
file_put_contents($dir, $data);
```

Note, you should use `curl()` for handling getting content from external URLs as a matter of principal. Safer and you have better control. Some hosts also block accessing external URLS using `file_get_contents` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the headers for the file (the headers contain the redirect).

```
$headerdata=get_headers($albumart);
echo($headerdata[4]);//show the redirect (for testing)
$actualloc=str_replace("Location: ","",$headerdata[4]);//remove the 'location' header string

file_put_contents($dir, $actualloc);
```

I think it's the 4th record in the header, if not check it with a print_r($hearderdata);

this will return the proper url of the image file.